# Finding the correct BPM/Time Signature

Tags: time-signatures, transcription, beats

[image]

I am trying to transcribe a music ([Pikon De Meta Fiction by Erabareshi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS4SG1e96Gg)), and even though this sync perfectly with the music, I don't feel comfortable with it (mainly because of the ties).
Do anyone has a suggestion for the correct BPM/Time Signature to make this look alright ?

Notes concerning the sheet music : the target instrument is an Alto Saxophone, I am also aware that I didn't set the correct key signature.

Comment: It looks as if the note values are all 50% too long. Try starting with a quarter note, two 8ths, quarter, two 8ths, quarter, etc.  You need to slow down the tempo in the same proportion, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You've set yourself the task of making a literal transcription of a very rhythmically free performance.  It's GOING to be full of ties.  It also needs to be readable, so the first job is to group the notes so that we can see where the beats are.  You may feel this introduces even MORE ties, but trust me, anyone having to read it will thank you!

I'm not sure which part of the track you are transcribing, so I can't speak on whether you've got it right!   But this version of your work is at least readable.

[image]

Comment: "I'm not sure which part of the track you are transcribing" - it took me a few listens to realise it was meant to be the start of the track! But anime soundtracks aren't my thing anyway...

Comment: Ah.  If that's meant to be the start of the track, I don't think you've correctly located where 'one' comes.  If I get time later I'll show you how I think it should be written.

Answer (score 0):

To find the tempo of a song, I use this website: http://www.tempotap.com/.

Here's what I got after testing it on your song:
[image]